# MS Excel perform Sumif and filter criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In cell H1 I want to sum D:D only if values are >0 `=SUMIF(D:D,">=0"`, but I also want to consider filtering which only works  by using `=SUBTOTAL(9,D:D)`, the problem is that I want both, how can I achieve that?

Comment: First point is that your sumif statement is missing its close bracket.

Comment: How do you think the results of the two expressions are going to differ, given that « 9 » in the subtotal expression means include manually hidden values?

Comment: @SolarMike that was just a typo